# Is "neither" used correctly here?

Tags: grammar

I know you can use "neither" in the next sentence if the previous one has a negation (e.g. don't, can't, etc.). I'm not sure about "never."

Example sentence:

> Your friendships never went beyond acquaintances. **Neither** could you
> find romance.

Comment: _Never_ is equivalent to a negation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage here is understandable (and perhaps reasonable, in casual contexts), but not strictly correct. The problem isn't so much in the words "neither" or "never," but in the lack of parallel construction. The second sentence is expecting the first to have another use of "could," like:

> **You never could** develop your acquaintances into friendships; **neither could you** find romance.

The need for parallel verb is mostly about this particular construction. This is fine:

> Your friendships never went beyond acquaintances. You couldn't find romance, either.